# Google web app/script to automatically upload files to a specific g-drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, windows-7, synchronization

I want to sync a specific directory on a local PC with a specific directory in google drive. I cannot employ gdrive open source app nor back up and sync

So I thought to work it out this way- When I visit a specific url (given by google web app), the files from a specific defined directory on a local PC are uploaded to the pre-defined directory in google drive. I must use a browser.

Is this possible with google app script or any google tool?
( I cannot emoply back and sync for this)

Answer (score 0):

I THINK you need to create HTML form to select and upload files

> **Why ?**

The form will be submitted to the external/local server and the browser will redirect away to the current address of the browser and append as query string parameters the values of the input fields with GET and objects with POST.

When a user visits an app or a program sends the app an `HTTP GET` request, Apps Script runs the function doGet(e). When a program sends the app an `HTTP POST` request, Apps Script runs doPost(e).

doPost() shall be used when comparatively large amount of sensitive data has to be sent and you need HTML form submitting to do that.

Comment: Chemiadel yes of course, but the part you mentioned is obviously very much possible with google web app. I want to know about the non-obvious parts - the possibility of automatically starting upload from pre-defined path after a user visits that web-app http link

Comment: A browser is not going to pick up any files from a local PC without the user selecting the file for upload, right? Wouldn't That would be a serious security risk? Also, which folder that opens when asked to upload is always determined by the PC not by the website, isn't it?